# jQuery: if div is in viewport do something for one time

Tags: jquery

I want to "bounce" a div for one time if it is in the viewport.

I have something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"    
src="js/jquery.viewport.js">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(function() {
   $(window).bind("scroll", function(event) {

    $(".DIV:in-viewport").each(function() {

      $( ".DIV" ).effect( "bounce", {times: 1, distance: 12}, 200);

    });
   });
);
```

Everything is fine and the div is bouncing when its in the viewport but what can I do to exit the function after bouncing one time. At the Moment it is bouncing all time when it is in theviewport.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want it to bounce once, the easiest way is to remove the "scroll" hook.

This will stop triggering the scroll after it has fired once.

```
$(function() {
  var bounce_my_div = function(event) {
    $(".DIV:in-viewport").each(function() {
      $( ".DIV" ).effect( "bounce", {times: 1, distance: 12}, 200);
    });

    $(window).unbind("scroll", bounce_my_div);
  };

  $(window).bind("scroll", bounce_my_div);
);
```

*Note: This will not animate if you later scroll the div off the screen and back into the viewport again. Once it bounces, it's done, forever (until you refresh the page)*

Comment: Thanks! But, like you wrote in the note, what can I do to animate the div everytime (for one time) when its is in the viewport?

Comment: Re-hook the event when it leaves the viewport, so that it will fire again. You can just re-use `$(window).bind("scroll", bounce_my_div);`. The tricky part is finding an event that triggers when it is no longer on screen. Probably use the scroll event for this, and calculate using the body's `scrollTop()` value and the element `.offset().top` and `.height()`.

Comment: You can mix this answer with Gary's solution, which uses `one` instead of `bind` and `unbind`. It's a bit cleaner that way, but you'll still want to re-hook when the element leaves the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with above about unbinding but you could also use the `one` event handler which only fires one time then unbinds automatically:

```
$(window).one("scroll", bounce_my_div);
```

Comment: I didn't know about that function! Amazing. (why isn't it called once? weird)